# Using Bernoulli distribution approximate the $q$-th moment

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $x$ be vector in $R^n$. Let $\pi(⋅)$  be a permutation on the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$  with a uniform distribution.  Let $|m|\leq n, m \in Z$.

Using Bernoulli (or maybe some other) distribution approimate the $q$-th moment
$$
E\left|\sum_{i=1}^mx_{\pi(i)}\right|^q, \quad q\geq 2.
$$

Thank you.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/291063/).